# Connecting to MSAccess database with PHP

Tags: php, ms-access, pdo, odbc

last several days I've been trying to connect to an MSAccess database (2000) using my PHP application (5.4.32) with no luck. 
I have explored a few examples I found on the web, and although it would appear the PHP script is finding the database OK, it seems to stop executing as soon as a connection request is issued.

My PHP Info can be found here: http://www.ve3gop.com/php_info.php

Critical components (PDO, pdo_mysql and PDO_ODBC) appear to be enabled.

I have tried 3 examples:
Example 1 Stops after connection request is sent.

```
<?php
$dbName = $_SERVER["SYSTEM_ROOT"] . "HockeyPool.mdb";
if (!file_exists($dbName)) {
    die("Could not find database file.");
}
else
{
echo "Using " . $dbName . " database.";
}

$db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$dbName; Uid=; Pwd=;");

echo "Connection Request Sent";

$sql  = "SELECT * FROM PoolTeams";
$result = $db->query($sql);
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    $teamIdent        = $row["ID"];
    $teamName         = $row["TeamName"];
}
?>
```

Example2 Same thing... stops after request sent.

```
<?php
$bits = 8 * PHP_INT_SIZE;
echo "(Info: This script is running as $bits-bit.)\r\n\r\n";
$dbName = "HockeyPool.mdb";

$dbh = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=HockeyPool.mdb");

echo "Request Sent";
$dbh = new PDO($connStr);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM PoolTeams";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();

while ($row = $sth->fetch()) {
    echo $row['PoolTeamName'] . "\r\n";
}
?>
```

And finally Example 3 doesn't work at all.

```
<?php

$conn = new COM('ADODB.Connection');
$dbName = $_SERVER["SERVER_ROOT"] . "HockeyPool.mdb";
echo $dbName;

 if (!file_exists($dbName)) {
    die("Could not find database file.");
 }

conn->Open("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$dbName");

echo $dbName;
$conn->close;

?>
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction to get my project off the ground? I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

TRY this:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=<Path>;"
```

If you have a password then try this to the end

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=<Path>;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=<Pass>;"
```

Comment: Just realised you are using MS Access 2k. You may need to change the provider to "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"

Comment: Hi Clint... thanks for getting back. Here is the modified code as per your suggestion... unfortunately it returns with an error indicating web page is unable to handle this request:     <?php
set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection");        
conn."Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;";       
conn.Open "HockeyPool.mdb";      



$conn->close;

?>

Comment: I should add that it seems to crash as soon as it encounters the first instruction $conn = new COM('ADODB.Connection');

Comment: GOT IT!!! I upgraded my PHP from 5.4.32 to 5.4.45 and started getting meaningful messages as to what's going on as opposed to the dreaded "couldn't handle request" errors. Turns out the COM component wasn't turned on in the php.ini file (in fact it was dropped from the ini file as of 5.4.2, which I didn't know). All I had to do is add a couple of lines to php.ini, restart server and voila! Thanks for getting back to me with  your suggestions Clint.

Comment: No worries mate. Sounds like you solved it yourself though!